# Reading from text file C

Tags: c

I have one char variable that holds number which represents examID(it's char because it has to be char). My text file looks like this:

```
5   1   Exam 1 (audit 31.10.)
6   1   Exam 2 (audit 23.10.)
14  1   Lab 01 (audit 21.11.)
16  1   Lab 02 (audit 28.11.)
...
```

First number in each line is examID, second is max num of points for that exam, end rest of text in line is exam name. I need to search text for examID match, and if it is match i need to store max num of points, and exam name in variables for later use. This is what i have so far:

```
char examName[100];
char tmp[100];
int  examID;
int  maxPoint=0;

FILE *fin=fopen("Exams.txt", "r");

while(fgets(tmp, sizeof(char)*100, fin)!=NULL) {
    sscanf(tmp, "%d", &examID);
    if(examID==s.examNum)
        printf("%d", examID);
}
```

So i found match and printed it, and it's ok, but i don't know how to read second number in line and name of exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
sscanf(tmp, "%d %d %[^\n]", &examID, &maxPoint, examName); 
if(examID==s.examNum)
    printf("%d %d %s\n", examID, maxPoint, examName);
```

`fgets` reads the full like, then `sscanf` parses it as the format string shows. So if you need a number, then number, then string (as in this case) you can use `"%d %d %[^\n]"`

Note: Since the `examName` has spaces (and is the list part of the text file before the newline) we use the negated scanset telling `sscanf` "I want everything until a newline is found stored as a string"

---

Side note, initialize your vairables:

```
char examName[100] = {'\0'};
char tmp[100] = {'\0'};
int  examID = 0;
```

Comment: Also a small note, there is no `&` provided to examName in `sscanf` because the identifier is already a pointer, it points to the first element of the array.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but it's just not working. output looks like this: 5 0 then some weird characters. 5 is correct number, 0 is wrong(in all examples i got 0 instead of right number) and string is completely out of this world

Comment: @yahzee - That's weird, first check my side note above and give it a try, sounds like uninitialized data. If it's still giving strange results maybe update with a fuller code sample. Given the above code you gave with that text file I'm seeing this work correctly.

Comment: i got it, examID and maxPoint were char in my program, i changed it to int and it now works. thanks for the help